# "More jobs near ..." uses wrong state

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

My Stack Overflow profile lists my location as: Saratoga, CA. The Careers 2.0 block on the main Stack Overflow questions page (correctly) lists a couple of jobs in my area.

But at the bottom of the Careers 2.0 block is a link: "More jobs near Saratoga".  When I click on that, it takes me to a page listing jobs near Saratoga, AR (resulting in zero jobs—so sad).

The "Where" box in that page only lists "Saratoga", so I'm guessing that's where it gets lost. If I change the text in the Where box to "Saratoga, CA", then a bunch of local jobs show up (as expected).

Comment: With about 500 people, I'm guessing Saratoga, Arkansas designates one "Community Technology-Thingy Fixer-Upper" to service all.

Comment: But you have to wait until he's done fixing Esther's Buick.

Comment: Maybe Stack Overflow careers wants you to move interstate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be resolved, would you have another look?

Comment: Works now. I tried when I was at work today, but it looks like it senses where the viewer is currently - so it knew I was in Mountain View.
Thanks!